# How to limit Canvas Delta manipulations in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, zooming

I have a canvas inside a Scrollviewer.Now I need to limit the manipulations of canvas.It is going beyond the scrollviewer and not visible.
I have my XAML code like this:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollView"
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                                  ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" ManipulationMode="All" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                        <canvas:CanvasControl x:Name="canvas" Height="560" Width="686"
                              Draw="Canvas_Draw" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta">
                        </canvas:CanvasControl>
```

And my cs file is like this:

```
private CompositeTransform dragTranslation;

canvas.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;
            dragTranslation = new CompositeTransform();
            canvas.RenderTransform = this.dragTranslation;

void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender,
    ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Move the rectangle.
            if (dragTranslation != null)
            {
                dragTranslation.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                dragTranslation.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
               // dragTranslation.Rotation += e.Delta.Scale / Math.PI;
                //dragTranslation.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
                //dragTranslation.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            }
            }
```

I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your ManipulationDelta handler you can check the results of the translation. Only commit it if the end point will be ok.

```
void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Move the rectangle.
    if (dragTranslation != null)
    {
         float newX = dragTranslation.TranslateX + e.Delta.Translation.X;
         float newY = dragTranslation.TranslateY + e.Delta.Translation.Y;
         if (IsInBounds(newX,newY))
         {
             dragTranslation.TranslateX = newX;
             dragTranslation.TranslateY = newY;
         }
    }
}
```

You can define IsInBounds appropriate to your scenario.

See my blog entry [Constraining manipulations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/10/constraining-manipulations.aspx) for more details and sample code.

Comment: Rob:But how do i check if my canvas is visible or not.I understood your blog but I believe that there is nothing related to my question.                                        Could you please give me some rough idea how to implement IsInBounds method?